# Shrinking plot area using plot() in R

Tags: r, graph, plot

I would like to shrink the width of my plot. In other words, I am looking to reduce the space between ticks on the x-axis, so that the points on the graph get closer to each other. I want the line to look more "compressed" on the x-axis. Is there a way of doing that?

Here is my current plot code:

```
 plot(ret.bull, type = "l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Return", xaxt = "n")
 abline(a = mean(ret.bull), b = 0, lty = 2)
```

[image]

I want to get something in those lines:

[image]
Thank you,

Comment: Change the axis limits or the plot width.

Comment: Changing the width isn't the solution, since it only makes the window plot smaller. I would like to leave the window as is, but the shrink the graph. Reducing the xlim doesn't work either since it cuts the data at the limit you set. What I want is reducing the space (distance) between the ticks.

Comment: It's not clear what you want since you show two graphs with different data and want the first graph to look like the second, which is not possible without changing the data.

Comment: I had to give an example of what I am looking for, but that doesn't mean that the two graphs are related. I think it is possible to increase the margin spaces, and decrease the space allocated to the graph within a window, so that it looks more "squished". I have posted another "representative" graph of what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes, change `xlim`. Decrease the lower limit, increase the upper limit.

Comment: Excellent. Can you post your comment as an answer so that I accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the aspect ratio by setting the `asp` argument to the plot function.  You can also open your graphics device at whatever dimensions you want (so a smaller width) using something like:

```
dev.new( width=4, height=6 )
```

Or you can just make one of the margins larger to reduce the space for the plot:

```
par(mar=c(5,4,2,10)+0.1)
```

Also the `squishplot` function in the TeachingDemos package is another way to change the aspect ratio (and put the empty space in the margins rather than leaving a large amount of white space inside the plotting region).

Comment: Thanks Greg. But sorry, changing the width isn't going to solve my problem. I don't want to have a tiny window with a compressed graph. I want to keep a medium sized window, but reduce the space (distance) between the x-axis ticks so that the graph is more "squished".

Comment: @Mariam, did you look at the `asp` or `squishplot` options?

Answer (score 2):

As Roland says, you just need to set your `xlim`. Plotting a single vector vertically, the default xlim is `c(1, length(ret.bull)`. You probably want something like

```
ret.bull <- rnorm(100) ## for reproducibility
plot(ret.bull, type = "l", xlim = c(-length(ret.bull), 2*length(ret.bull)))
```